# Help with LeadConvert Trigger Class? (Creating multiple contacts from one lead)

Tags: apex, class, lead-conversion

I've written a few classes for this trigger i'm working on and while I can get 100% coverage for these classes and I can't get more than 0% on the trigger.

In the sandbox, this trigger works just fine. I'm able to create +2 additional contact records on the Account without issue. Though, due to the 0% coverage there's no way I can deploy it to our production environment from the sandbox.

How would I best write a class to validate this trigger?

```
trigger CreateMoreLeadContacts on Lead (after update) {

list < Contact > listContacts = new List < Contact>();

for(Lead objLead : trigger.new) {

if(objlead.IsConverted && !trigger.oldMap.get(objLead.Id).IsConverted) {

Contact c1=New Contact(
LastName=objLead.Secondary_Lead_Contact_Name__c,
Phone=objLead.Secondary_Lead_Phone__c,
Email=objLead.Secondary_Lead_Email__c);

c1.AccountId = objLead.ConvertedAccountId;
listContacts.add(c1);

Contact c2=New Contact(
LastName=objLead.Tertiary_Lead_Contact_Name__c,
Phone=objLead.Tertiary_Lead_Phone__c,
Email=objLead.Tertiary_Lead_Email__c);

c2.AccountId = objLead.ConvertedAccountId;
listContacts.add(c2);

     }

    }

    if ( listContacts.size() > 0 )
        insert listContacts;

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your test method you just create a lead as in `Lead l = new Lead(all your field assignments here);
Insert l;
update l;
Your system assertions here`

Comment: Much obliged @ideasforce. I'm new to all of this. The update portion was what I was missing from the test unit.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Great! It is specially important because your trigger is after update, you should always perform the DML operation that will fire your trigger.